# iPhone: rendering of different views possible?

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, uitextview, render

I have a problem, I can't solve properly.

In short: I want to create a single view (say: UIImageView) out of multiple subviews - i.e. it consists out of multiple ImageViews and TextViews. The thing is, I want to sort of 'render' them to be a single View.

Say, I take an image, add some description below, add a title above, and maybe another little image at the bottom. I want this whole thing to be a single UIImage to make it sort of 'listen' to one (e.g.) swiping gesture, which I cant tell to bring the new image to display.

Does anyone know the best way to achieve this? So far my results were fairly poor.

Any hints are welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is definitely possible. You seem to know about views and subviews, but should also read up on the "UIResponder" class and the "responder chain". The master view that you want to contain them all **won't be** a UIImageView, though, because that exists to just show an image. You can make all the ones you talk about subviews (addSubview: or in Interface Builder) of a plain UIView that you subclass yourself (say, MyContainerView), which then itself handles the gestures. If you want to take advantage of free scrolling on swipe, you could instead put your container view into a UIScrollView, which has its own set of semantics that you can leverage. For this latter, you should check out Apple's sample code for scroll views (don't have a link handy but should be easy to find) which embeds multiple image views in a scroll view.